# Kotlin - share viewmodel between data based on selection

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I want to share viewmodel between fragments, let's say that I have a fragmentA which display a recycler view with element (viewholders) and when I click on one of them I want to the element to be displayed in frangmentB for a detail view.
So far I have identified two ways to do it.
1)Having a super viewmodel which is share among fragments and hold the reference on the selected viewmodel like this :

```
class ShareHappyPlaceModel : ViewModel() {
    val happyPlace: MutableLiveData<HappyPlaceModel> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

2)Transform the view model into a data class which implement parcable and share it through the navigation between fragment. Then in fragmentB recreate a viewmodel from the data class object.

The first one seems not elegant as I rather have a reference share only to fragementB than across all fragment.
The second bother with the fact that I need to transform a viewmodel into an intermediary class.

What is your opinion ?

Comment: Are you sure you need a shared viewModel? Can't you just pass the selected item as an argument for the new fragment? If you really need to share a viewModel between multiple fragments and you use navigation components, you can use `by navGraphViewModels`.

Comment: As I want to display details on the second Fragement so for me the information should be store in a viewmodel but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same view model for both fragments [here is](https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments) one good article about it. But I think it is not suitable for you. The problem with your case you have recyclerView at the first fragment. So as I understand every item in recyclerView has its own view model. FragmentB's and recycler item's view models can't share the same parent. So item passing looks more healthy on your case.

Comment: I think they are using the share viewmodel approach.